# How to call class's method using jquery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am newbie in Jquery and Ajax.. Please bear with my stupid problem..

i am trying to call method say test() inside class **hello** through ajax call..

**hello.php**

```
class hello
{
      public function test()
      {
        //some data
      }

      public function abc()
      {
        //some data
      }
}
```

now i want to call **test()** from another php file...

for example:

**b.php**

```
  $.ajax({
    url : 'hello.php->test()', //just for example i have written it bcz it should call only test() not abc()..
   })
```

is it possible to call it directly? i have went through $.ajax() api but i din't found anything helpful..

All answer will be appreciates...

Comment: AJAX just calls a single web address (so a PHP file, in your case). If it's possible to declare a class in one PHP file (say a.php) and then access it in another PHP file (b.php), then yes this can be done - but the AJAX call won't be any different, you'll be calling `b.php`, the JavaScript doesn't care what that PHP file does provided it returns a usable response.

Comment: You are not directly calling any PHP methods via AJAX. AJAX is just a way of making a request to the Server dynamically. This request could be handled any way you want.

Comment: you cann't call it from outside as it is private to hello

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's a public function - all you have to do is instantiate hello then it's visible.

Comment: put the class in a separated file.
You'll have:hello.class.php, a.php, b.php. With that, you can freely call Hello->test() in a.php or b.php

Comment: @ArunPJohny i updated my question properly please check

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton no... it is a closure function... it is not a member function...

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's not a closure in any way. Read about visibility: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton thought it was javascript... my bad

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to pass the name of the class, the constructor arguments, and the method name and arguments etc. via ajax POST or GET, for example:

```
var url = 'callMethod.php';
var data = {
    str_className: 'Hello',
    arr_consArgs: {arg1: 'test1'},
    str_methodName: 'test'
};
$.post(url, data, function(response) {
    etc.
});
```

In PHP script named `callMethod.php`:

```
/* Place your 'Hello' class here */

// class
$str_className = !empty($_POST["str_className"]) ? $_POST["str_className"] : NULL;
if ($str_className) {
    // constructor
    $arr_consArgs = !empty($_POST["arr_consArgs"]) ? $_POST["arr_consArgs"] : array();

    // method
    $str_methodName = !empty($_POST["str_methodName"]) ? $_POST["str_methodName"] : NULL;
    if (!empty($str_methodName)) {
        $arr_methodArgs = !empty($_POST["arr_methodArgs"]) ? $_POST["arr_methodArgs"] : array();
    }

    // call constructor
    $obj = fuNew($str_className, $arr_consArgs);

    // call method
    $output = NULL;
    if (!empty($str_methodName)) 
        $output .= call_user_func_array(array($obj, $str_methodName), $arr_methodArgs);

    // echo output
    echo $output;

}
```

where:

```
function fuNew($classNameOrObj, $arr_constructionParams = array()) {
    $class = new ReflectionClass($classNameOrObj);
    if (empty($arr_constructionParams))
        return $class->newInstance();
    return $class->newInstanceArgs($arr_constructionParams);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**hello.php**

```
class hello
{
      public function test()
      {
        //some data
      }

      public function abc()
      {
        //some data
      }
}
if(isset($_GET['method'])){
   $hello = new hello;
   $hello->$_GET['method']();
}
```

**b.php**

```
 $.ajax({
    url : 'hello.php?method=test', //just for example i have written it bcz it should call only test() not abc()..
   })
```

By they way, it's not secure to expose your class via ajax requests.